# Form Submits once jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have multiple forms on the same page and i am submitting them using jquery.

I am using the following code:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
//Submit form ajax
});
```

The issue is it only sends once. When I click the submit button again it doesnt do anything. How can this be solved?

Comment: There should be unique `submit` buttons for each `forms` and that should be wrapped within the `form`

Comment: what is happening in the ajax

Comment: Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You may have a js error, watch your console.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to send multiple forms with a single submit. Although this is not advised (should convert your code into one form), the issue causing this may be event delegation or improper binding/unbinding of the elements. If it works once I suspect this is the case.

Maybe you can correct it like this.

```
$(function() {
    $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Submit form ajax
    });
});
```

Comment: I was thinking this was the right answer, but when I implement it and click the submit button on a form. it reloads the page, I put a alert('working'); to make sure it triggers but its not

Comment: In that case you need to prevent the HTML submit, and submit strictly through AJAX. Also make sure that you are waiting until the DOM is ready. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work in my example
can you post your code?

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
alert("submit");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think his code is like yours, I think OP has multiple `<form>` blocks.